# Calling the PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self) error Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, imagepicker

I have an image picker with a "Manage" button. In this case you will have the menu to permit access to all pictures, select more pictures or keep the current selection.

As the image picker starts this pops up automatically and when you click select more pictures I get the limited image picker, which is fine. But if you close this limited picker and use the "Manage" button, I get this error:

```
App[39324:2140958] [Presentation] Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x111012000> on <App.GalleryViewController: 0x11101b200> (from <App.GalleryViewController: 0x11101b200>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

I tried several things but without success. This is my code:

I have a GalleryWorker.swift file:

```
    func createAlertLimited(delegate: GalleryDisplayLogic?) -> UIAlertController {
        let alertLimitedController = UIAlertController(title: "The app needs access to your photos",
                                                message: "",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let allPhotosAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Allow access to all pictures", style: .default) { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
                        assertionFailure("Not able to open privacy settings")
                        return
                }
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }

        let selectPhotosAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Select more pictures", style: .default) { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                let galleryVC = GalleryViewController()
                galleryVC.displayLimitedPicker()
            }
        }
      
        let keepSelectionAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Keep current selection", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in })
        
        alertLimitedController.addAction(allPhotosAction)
        alertLimitedController.addAction(selectPhotosAction)
        alertLimitedController.addAction(keepSelectionAction)
        
        return alertLimitedController
    }
```

And I have the GalleryViewController.Swift where I call this:

```
    func displayLimitedPicker() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization() { result in
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self)
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could it be an instance issue? What's the link between `GalleryViewController` & `GalleryWorker`? How is called `createAlertLimited(delegate:)`?

Comment: I have a GalleryPresenter.swift for this: weak var viewController: SDGalleryDisplayLogic? where I call also: let alertLimitedController = self.worker.createAlertLimited(delegate: self.viewController)

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly telling you what is wrong:

```
App.GalleryViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

This means that `GalleryViewController.view` is not in the view hierarchy.

Either you need to make it a root view controller:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = galleryViewController
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Or add it to a view controller with that does have its view in the view hierarchy:

```
existingViewController.addChild(galleryViewController)
existingViewController.view.addSubview(galleryViewController.view)
```

Or present it (example for using navigation controller):

```
navigationController?.present(galleryViewController, animated: true)
```